# Can execute immediate be used with JSON_TABLE

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I need to convert JSON into data table (key value columns) in Oracle 12c v12.1.0.2

So for example there is a JSON string like

`{"ID": 10, "Description": "TestJSON", "status":"New"}`

I need this converted to :

```
Column1          Column2
------------------------------------
ID                  10
Description         TestJSON
status              New
```

Now my JSON string could change the number of attributes and hence I require to keep the conversion dynamic.

I tried using execute immediate :

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
sqlsmt VARCHAR2(200);
t3 varchar2(50);
begin
sqlsmt := 'SELECT * '||
'FROM  json_table( ( select jsonstr from mytable where ID= 10) , ''$[*]'' '||
                'COLUMNS (  :t1 PATH ''$.''|| '':t2'' ))';
execute immediate sqlsmt into t3 using 'desc' , '$.Description' ;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Output Variable: ' || t3);
END;
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
ORA-06512: at line 8
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Please help. I have Oracle 12c V1. But I really need to pull columns dynamically from JSON.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL - will the JSON field name and/or the output column really be supplied at runtime?

Comment: The JSON input may vary in number of key value pairs. So the requirement is to keep the JSON dynamic.

Comment: The JSON is a variable; the question is whether `desc` (which is illegal) and `Description` will vary when you run this?

Comment: ok so we are trying to implement configurable forms in our application. Tomorrow say a new column gets added to the form, I need to get value of the new column from the JSON. We have configured column names in a database table which match the field name in the JSON. I wanted to run a loop to pass those field names to the JSON and get its value. This way if any new column is added to my form field master, we will be able to dynamically fetch its value from the JSON. I hope I was able to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that can help with dynamic SQL (assuming you really need to use it). The first is to use `dbms_output` to show the generated statement before you try to execute it; so in your case:

```
...
dbms_output.put_line(sqlsmt);
execute immediate sqlsmt into t3;
--using 'descr' , '$.Description' ;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Output Variable: ' || t3);
END;
/
```

with your code that shows:

```
SELECT * FROM  json_table( ( select jsonstr from mytable where ID= 10) , '$[*]' COLUMNS (  :t1 PATH '$.'|| ':t2' ))
```

The most obvious issue there is in `'$.'|| ':t2'`, where `:t2` shouldn't be in quotes; that isn't causing the error but would stop it being bound to your variable as you expect as it's a literal value. You also have the `$.` part in that bit and in your variable value, but again it isn't getting that far.

In common with all dynamic SQL, you can only supply values for variables in the `using` clause. You're trying to pass the column name as a bind variable, which isn't allowed; so it's trying to use `:t1` as the output column name, not `desc`; and `:t1` isn't a valid name. (Neither is `desc` as that's a reserved word - but either gets the same error.) So, you have to concatenate the column name in rather than binding it.

It looks like you would be able to use `:t2` for the path though; but you you can't do that either, not as a dynamic SQL restriction but as a SQL/JSON one - if you got that far, with a valid variable value, you'd still get "ORA-40454: path expression not a literal". You have to concatenate the path into the statement too.

Finally the `$[*]` doesn't allow you to match the `Description`... which leads to the second hint about dynamic SQL; get a static query working properly first, then make that dynamic.

So putting that together, you could do:

```
declare
  sqlsmt varchar2(200);
  t1 varchar2(30) := 'descr';
  t2 varchar2(30) := 'Description';
  t3 varchar2(50);
begin
  sqlsmt := 'SELECT * '||
    'FROM  json_table( ( select jsonstr from mytable where ID= 10) , ''$'' '||
    'COLUMNS ( ' || t1 || ' PATH ''$.' || t2 || '''))';
  dbms_output.put_line(sqlsmt);
  execute immediate sqlsmt into t3;
  dbms_output.put_line( 'Output Variable: ' || t3);
end;
/
```

which with your example data outputs:

```
SELECT * FROM  json_table( ( select jsonstr from mytable where ID= 10) , '$' COLUMNS ( descr PATH '$.Description'))
Output Variable: TestJSON
```

It's a bit odd that the only thing you are allowed to pass as a variable, the 10, is hard-coded. But I get this is an experiment.

You could also write the statement as:

```
select j.*
from mytable t
cross join json_table ( t.jsonstr, '$' columns ( descr path '$.Description' )) j
where t.id = 10;
```

which you could do dynamically as:

```
declare
  sqlsmt varchar2(200);
  id number := 10;
  t1 varchar2(30) := 'descr';
  t2 varchar2(30) := 'Description';
  t3 varchar2(50);
begin
  sqlsmt := 'select j.*'
    || ' from mytable t'
    || q'^ cross join json_table ( t.jsonstr, '$' columns ( ^'
    || t1
    || q'^ path '$.^'
    || t2
    || q'^' )) j^'
    || ' where t.id = :id';
  dbms_output.put_line(sqlsmt);
  execute immediate sqlsmt into t3 using id;
  dbms_output.put_line( 'Output Variable: ' || t3);
end;
/
```

I've used [the alternative quoting mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218) to avoid having to double-up the quotes within the statement, but that's optional. With the same data that outputs:

```
select j.* from mytable t cross join json_table ( t.jsonstr, '$' columns ( descr path '$.Description' )) j where t.id = :id
Output Variable: TestJSON
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ff9e96f6fbc1348ad34e67bb353581d9)

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution !! I really appreciate your in detail response. The query did work for me. I will try to implement it in a loop in my stored procedure. Thanks again !